# Set TextView width according to other View's width

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `ImageView`, the image is loaded from the net and can vary in width. 
Below I have a `TextView` with a description of the image. I want the `TextView` to be exactly as wide as the `ImageView`.

My try was this:

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/imagedescription"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textAppearance="@style/SmallTextGray" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

which somehow works as the `TextView`'s width is set accoring to that of the `ImageView`, but the `TextView` end after 2 lines:

[image]

I know I could set the `TextView`'s width programmatically after I know the image's width, but is there also a way to do it in the XML layout?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if it will work, but try doing in your code, after load the image:

```
textView.setWidth(imageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth());
```

Answer (score 4):

With a small change of layout: replace `LinearLayout` with a `RelativeLayout`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/imagedescription"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/iv"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/iv"
        android:layout_below="@+id/iv"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textAppearance="@style/SmallTextGray" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This way the TextView is always below imageView and its bounds are aligned to imageViews

Answer (score 1):

```
You can use weight like this:

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="5">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:text="2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="3" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the wight property in xml and give equal weight to both imageview and textview. then both size will be equal

Comment: @ Rushabh Patel .. I was unable to add code in comments as commnet has limited charecters. so only added as seperate answer. By the way I dont think by writing multiple answers, we get more Reputaion. Just wanted to share knowledge and help someone..

Comment: then you can write all the suggestion in to your one answer if you know how to edit the answer again and again.

Answer (score 0):

In your case do this:

```
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/imagedescription"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1"

                android:textAppearance="@style/SmallTextGray" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This will only work in a horizontal LinearLayout or for height in a vertical LinearLayout. Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: I think you are using vertical linearlayout only. anyways good that you got the solution..

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                  android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/controller"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

        <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TableLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <TableRow>
                    <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:text="asdasdasasasdasdasdasdasdasdasdadasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdsadasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdsdasdasdasdsadsadsadasdasdsadsadsadasdasdasdasdasdasddasdasdasdasdasdasdasdsadasdasdasdasdasdasdsadasdasdsa..."/>
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]  [image]

Comment: Doesn't seem like the TextView's width is aligned with the image, does it? Thank you anyway, I guess I'll do it programmatically according to Renan's answer.

Comment: @Ascorbin sorry, forgot that was the requirement, updated my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try This.This will work

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

   <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
       android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"       
      android:orientation="vertical" >

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/iv"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
          />

       <TextView
          android:id="@+id/imagedescription"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
          android:typeface="monospace" />
        </LinearLayout>

      </LinearLayout>
```